# Denominação/Nomenclatura do Jade template engine

Tags: convenções-de-nome, jade

Olá , há alguns dias estou recebendo uma mensagem quando vou instalar a Template Engine Jade via `npm` , a mesagem diz:

```
npm WARN deprecated jade@1.11.0: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
```

A minha pergunta é a seguinte , o Jade template Engine agora se chama pug ? Os arquivos .jade vão usar a extensão .pug ?
Estou meio confuso quanto a isso.. =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É, é verdade... por questões juridicas de direitos à marca/nome *Jade*.

o [repositório JADE da NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jade) aponta para o [Github antigo](https://github.com/jadejs/jade) ainda. Lá confirma-se.

O novo repositório no Github é https://github.com/pugjs/pug e o novo pacote NPM é https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug

Neste issue do Github dá para seguir o estado da transição (à data de hoje ainda não completa): https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2184

Comment: Obrigado @Sergio , eu estava bem confuso se continuava a usar arquivos .jade ou se mudaria para .pug , agora vou começar a usar somente .pug