# Jade variáveis dinamicas

Tags: node.js, express.js, jade, pug

Existe alguma forma de renderizar variáveis dinâmicas em jade com expressjs, quando eu digo dinâmica é que se alterem em um loop sem reload na pagina.

```
...
    app.set('view engine','jade');    
    app.get('/',function(req,res}{
          res.render('index.jade',{name:'Rafael'})
        })
```

A intenção é dar um refresh no `res.render` alterando o `{name:Rafael}` para `{name:Maria}`(exemplo) mantendo o layout gerado estático.
Tem como? com socket ou ajax?

Answer (score 2):

Para fazer o que queres tens de usar AJAX.

Escolhe uma rota para o AJAX e renderiza o conteúdo que precisas numa string. Para fazer isso passa uma callback ao `.render`:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('/partials', {name:'Rafael'}, (err, html) => {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        var str = encodeURIComponent(html);
        res.send({html: str});
    });
});
```

Assim envias um JSON de volta para o Browser e lá usas a string de HTML no conteúdo que precisares.

No exemplo usei `{name:'Rafael'}` mas podes passar ao Jade os dados que quiseres claro.

> Nota: O Jade agora chama-se Pug. O Jade foi abandonado. [Podes ler mais sobre isso aqui.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/127263/129)

Comment: Tentei implementar a ideia soque não deu muito certo ou não entendi a ideia, esse html retornado não vai substituir o tmp que ja foi renderizado?

Comment: @RafaelVergoPolan vou tentar mais logo acrescentar um exemplo de ajax se não sabes como implementar isso.