# Passa dados recebido do servidor para o Javascript do Cliente

Tags: javascript, html, html5, aplicação-web

Suponha que eu tenho a seguinte página feito em HTML que mostra o nome {{name}} e data {{ date}} ambas as informações vieram do servidor:

```
<h1>Seu nome é {{name}} </h1>
<h1> A data de hoje é {{date}}</h1>
```

Porém, como eu faria se hipoteticamente eu quiser passar o valor contido em **{{date}}** para a seguinte função (script) agregada ao html enviado (?):

```
<script>

function mostradata (date) {
    alert(date)
  }

</script>
```

Resumindo: quero que minha função mostradata recebe o parametro **{{date}}** que veio do servidor.

Comment: Sugiro que de uma olhada no template engine Jade. E já tem uma resposta aqui também. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/198999/passar-variável-para-página-html-com-nodejs

Comment: pq não cria uma variável com o valor de `{{date}}` e usa depois?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

isso é bem simples na verdade, você tem que ter conciencia que é possivel pegar valores do seu HTML com JS, basta usar document.getElementById ou document.getElementByClass dentre outros.

Digamos que você optou em usar getElementByid

Você dever declarar id, então podemos fazer o seguinte:

```
<h1 id="myId"> A data de hoje é {{date}}</h1>
```

E agora com JS você pega esse elemento:

```
<script>

function mostradata () {

    return document.getElementById("myId").textContent

  }

console.log(mostradata())


</script>
```

Com esse script toda a vez que você atualizar a pagina ele vai chamar essa função e pegar conteudo do texto da tag que tenha o id myId e nesse caso exibir no console.

Agora se o caso for pegar somente a data é só adaptar esse código, ao invés de você passar o id para o H1 é só criar uma TAG filho dentro do H1, pode ser por exemplo um span, então:

```
<h1> A data de hoje é <span id="myId">{{date}}</span></h1>
```