# Como carregar varias rotas no node.js em um .jade

Tags: node.js, rotas, jade, pug

Existe alguma forma de carregar várias rotas dentro de um mesmo arquivo `.jade`, por exemplo:
 
Posso ter uma rota `/menu`, outra `/header`, outra `/clientes`, quando chamar a rota `/clientes` dou um `res.render('clientes')` e chamar as três em um arquivo só, tipo:

```
html
  body
    [Inclui a rota /header]
    [Inclui a rota /menu]
    [faz a lógica da tela de clientes]
```

Answer (score 0):

Um exemplo com 2 ficheiros:

Ficheiro `layout.pug`:

```
html
  head
    title O meu site
    // etc...
  body
    block bodyPagina
```

Ficheiro `contactos.pug`

```
extends ./layout.pug

block bodyPagina // aqui continuas o conteúdo do body definido no layout
  h1 Olá mundo!
  p Hoje está um lindo dia!
```

O ficheiro a ser chamado pelo express no `res.render` deve ser sempre a página mais especifica, neste caso o `contactos.pug`.

---

**Nota:** estou a usar a extenção `.pug` pois [o Jade foi substituído pelo Pug](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127261/129).