# Pra que serve o comando "res.send()" em Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Estou estudando NodeJS para fins acadêmicos e durante a implementação de um projeto me deparei com esse comando. Pra que ele serve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Node.js é um motor, essa função pode ser de qualquer "lib", no caso provavelmente é do Express, que é uma lib que pode ser usada junto com NodeJS

No caso você deve ter escrito errado, deve se referir a `.send()`, em um exemplo:

```
var express = require('express'); //Importa a lib express

var app = express();//Inicia a lib

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Olá mundo');
});
```

Cada argumento tem um significado:

- `req` é a interface de requisição HTTP, você pode pegar o cabeçalho enviado pelo cliente/navegador, por exemplo pode pegar um upload
- `res` é a interface de resposta HTTP, você pode enviar cabeçalhos e o corpo para o navegador.

O `req` (requisição) e `res` (resposta) em `app.get('/', function (req, res) {`, são os mesmos objetos que o Node fornece, para que seja possível chamar o `req.pipe()`, `req.on('data', callback)` e qualquer outra coisa que desejaria fazer sem o envolvimento do Express.

> Mais detalhes clicando na tag: [express](/questions/tagged/express)

Note que os nomes deles podem mudar em `function(req, res)`, pode fazer assim:

```
app.get('/', function(foo, bar) {
  bar.send('Olá mundo');
});
```

Então **`.send()`** envia para a resposta HTTP algo que você desejar, por exemplo se fizer isso:

```
app.get('/foo/bar', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Olá mundo');
});
```

Ao acessar a url `http://meusite.com/foo/bar` você irá visualizar isto na página:

```
Olá mundo
```

A resposta HTTP que chegará no browser deve ser algo como:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 10 Oct 2017 23:26:07 GMT
Content-Length: 10
Content-Type: text/html

Olá mundo!
```

> A primeira quebra de linha, após o ultimo header é o que divide o cabeçalho do corpo

Então essa resposta HTTP irá ser renderizada pelo navegador, é importante entender isto porque a comunicação HTTP funciona com estas duas etapas, ou seja é assim que os sites funcionam, o navegador envia uma requisição o servidor/script processa e devolve uma resposta (que você programou), algo como isto:

[image: http]

### Views no Express

O Express tem outro métodos chamado `.render` para popular views e enviar como resposta, isto não tem necessariamente haver com http pois ocorre antes, ou seja é processado no servidor.

Antes do Express poder renderizar arquivos de modelo, as seguintes configurações do aplicativo devem ser feitas:

`views` é o diretório onde os arquivos de modelo estão localizados, por exemplo:

```
app.set('views', './views')
```

`view engine` é o mecanismo de modelo a ser usado, por Exemplo:

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade')
```

Em seguida instale o pacote `npm` correspondente ao mecanismo de modelo, digite isto no terminal/cmd:

```
 npm install jade --save
```

Após o mecanismo de visualização estar configurado, você não precisa especificar o mecanismo ou carregar o módulo do mecanismo de modelo no seu aplicativo; o Express carrega o módulo internamente, como mostrado abaixo (para o exemplo acima).

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

Crie um arquivo de modelo do Jade chamado `index.jade` no diretório views, com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
html
  head
    title!= title
  body
    h1!= message
```

Em seguida crie uma rota para renderizar o arquivo `index.jade`. Se a propriedade `view engine` não estiver configurada, é preciso especificar a extensão do arquivo view. Caso contrário, é possível omiti-la.

Você pode criar um estrutura para passar os dados assim `{ title: 'Meu titulo', message: 'Olá mundo!'}`, deve ficar mais ou menos assim:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Meu titulo', message: 'Olá mundo!'});
});
```

Ao fazer uma solicitação à página inicial, o arquivo `index.jade` será renderizado como HTML.

Comment: entendi. Mas me tire por favor uma outra dúvida, esta resposta enviada pelo .send() para a view pode ser "atribuída" a alguma variável na view?

Comment: @MonitorLPI .send não tem haver com view, talvez vc esteja falando de `res.render`, que é uma outra função: https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L985, é isso?

Comment: Estou me referindo ao .send() mesmo. Bom, é que na resposta você disse que o send() envia para a resposta HTTP o que você deseja e que esta resposta é que aparece nessa página, então achei que essa resposta pudesse ser atribuída a algum lugar. Fiquei confuso sobre o porque de executar esse comando para enviar uma resposta já que a página de resposta vai ficar "em branco" apenas com essa resposta enviada, mas acho isso já é conteúdo pra outra pergunta. Obrigado por responder e pela paciência.

Comment: @MonitorLPI editei a resposta, adicionei sobre o `Views no Express`, nesse exemplo usasse o Jade.

Comment: @MonitorLPI deve dá pra fazer sem Jade, assim que eu conseguir testar eu posto um exemplo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento `+1`. Sugiro mudares `jade` para `pug`. O [Jade foi abandonado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/127261/129)

Answer (score -3):

@MonitorLPI

Basicamente esse é um código para rodar um servidor node na porta 3000:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('<h1>Olá mundo</h1>')
})

app.listen(3000,  (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Não foi possível rodar o servidor do JobFy');
  }else {
    console.log('Servidor rodando');
  }
})
```

Essa parte do método send() pode ser colocada em uma variável sim, porém tem que ser o a função toda. Ex:

```
const server = app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('<h1>Olá mundo</h1>')
})
```

então na parte onde o servidor fica escutando a requisição para responder, você pode usar assim:

```
server.listen(3000,  (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Não foi possível rodar o servidor do JobFy');
  }else {
    console.log('Servidor rodando');
  }
})
```

Perceba que o método send ficou dentro de "server".
"send()" é um envio. Pode usar 0 "end()" também, porém o html fica sem o "charset UTF-8". 
Normalmente a galera usar o render().