# Porque e quando usar o "res.send()" em uma aplicação? NodeJS e Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

Bom, sou iniciante em NodeJS e comecei a estudar para fins acadêmicos. Em outra pergunta que fiz aqui no SO-BR ([Pra que serve o comando "res.send()" em Express?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/244489/pra-que-serve-o-comando-res-send-em-express/244493?noredirect=1#244493)) eu perguntei pra que servia esse comando e que foi respondida muito bem, mas o problema agora é que eu não faço a mínima ideia do porque usar esse comando e quando usar. Poderiam me explicar e se possível exemplificar? Agradeço desde já a colaboração e paciência de todos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O comando res.send serve para servidor enviar resposta ao cliente web.

No express ele pode ser usado para responder numa rota do servidor, como no exemplo abaixo para retornar o resultado do servidor mediante aquele pedido na URL informada usando um request GET no caminho /user:

1)No arquivo principal da sua aplicação app.js carregar o arquivo de rotas para todas as rotas a partir de /:

```
// router
app.use('/', require('./routes'));
```

2)No arquivo routes/index.js indicar que para a rota /user o servidor vai responder com um texto com o conteúdo dentro do parêntesis. Envia-se também o código de resposta 201 sinalizando resposta com sucesso:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/user', (request, response) => {
    response.status(201);
    response.send("RESPOSTA TEXTO");
});
```

Comment: Humm... acho que entendi um pouco. Vou pesquisar mais à respeito. Obrigado por responder!